# Stetic in MonoDevelop

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, monodevelop

I've read online that I can use something called Stetic to edit the GUI objects (such as forms) in a visual way (similar to VisualStudio) in MonoDevelop.  I can't find anything however, on how to install Stetic into my copy of MonoDevelop.  I'm on Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stetic is built-in. Simply create a new GTK# project.

Comment: Is it only available for C# or can I use it for VB.net?